# Svg zoom to specific rect

Tags: javascript, svg, viewbox

I have SVG with multiple grouped elements. What I to do is to zoom to secific group.

I already got rect with `{top, left, width, height}` that I would like to zoom to (change `viewBox` attribute of my SVG).

Any easy way to calculate the right values for the `viewBox`?

Comment: Surely you just set the viewBox to `"top left width height"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the viewBox to equal "top left width height":

Here's a simple example. Clicking on either rectangle will zoom the screen on that rectangle. Clicking on it again will return the screen to its original zoom.

```js
var selected = false;
var svg = document.getElementById('svg');

var zoomOnElement = function(e) {
    if (e.target === selected) {
 // Deselect element
 svg.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 600 400");
 selected = false;
    } else {
 // Select element
 selected = e.target;
 var viewBox = selected.getAttribute('x');
 viewBox += " " + selected.getAttribute('y')
 viewBox += " " + selected.getAttribute('width')
 viewBox += " " + selected.getAttribute('height')
 svg.setAttribute("viewBox", viewBox);
    }
}

document.getElementById('rect-1').addEventListener("click", zoomOnElement);
document.getElementById('rect-2').addEventListener("click", zoomOnElement);
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300" height="200" viewBox="0 0 600 400" id="svg">

   <rect id="background" width="600" height="400" fill="#eee"/>
   <rect id="rect-1" x="100" y="50" width="50" height="300" fill="red"/>
   <rect id="rect-2" x="225" y="175" width="300" height="50" fill="blue"/>
   
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks! Works great! I new about the attribute but in my case this didn't work same way... so I thought I had to calculate somehow these values... but I found bug in my code ;)